# Javascript onClick opens first image only

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, window

I'm having some trouble with my onClick event. No matter which image I click on it always opens the first image on the page. It just won't open any other image.

**javascript**:

```
function opennew() {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.style.width=130+"px";
    largeImage.style.height=130+"px";
    var url=largeImage.getAttribute('src');
    window.open(url,'Image','width=largeImage.stylewidth,
       height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1');
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="oneitem">
  <div><img id="largeImage"  onClick="opennew();" src="Books-001.jpg" />
  </div>
  <p>Caption goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do they all have an `id` attribute of `"largeImage"`?

Comment: Yes, each image had the id of "largeImage" .

Answer (score 0):

are you using for every img the same ID attribute largeImage?

Id is an unique field and you are only allowed to use one ID Name within a Page.

Solution would be that you do someting like this:

Html:

```
<div class="oneitem">
    <div>
      <img id="1"  onClick="opennew(1);" src="Books-001.jpg" />
     </div><p>Caption goes here</p>
</div>

<div class="oneitem">
    <div>
        <img id="2"  onClick="opennew(2);" src="Books-001.jpg" />
    </div><p>Caption goes here</p>
 </div>
```

Js:

```
function opennew(Id) {
var largeImage = document.getElementById(Id);
largeImage.style.display = 'block';
largeImage.style.width=130+"px";
largeImage.style.height=130+"px";
var url=largeImage.getAttribute('src');
window.open(url,'Image','width=largeImage.stylewidth,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1');
}
```